# Tomcat Eats up Memory IN VM

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-management

I have deployed my web application to `Apache Tomcat 6`.

This application captures user clicks on all sites on the organization's domain. Because of this, it always has a huge load on its application servers. I have 8 Linux servers running as app servers with 16 GB Ram. My issue is that `Tomcat` uses up all this RAM and I have to restart these servers every two hours to free up the memory. Could you please suggest any way how I can free up this memory without restarting Tomcat.

I have updated my `java_opts= "-server -d64 -Xms6144M -Xmx6145M`

Comment: Why blaming it on tomcat, chances are your application might be the actual culprit.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problem is that your application has one or more memory leaks.

There are numerous resources on how to find memory leaks in Java code.  Here is a small selection:

- Oracle's ["Troubleshooting Guide for Java SE 6 with HotSpot VM"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html#gbywf).
- [How to find a Java Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119/how-to-find-a-java-memory-leak)
- [Suggestions for finding a memory leak in a web application running in Apache Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343861/suggestions-for-finding-a-memory-leak-in-a-web-application-running-in-apache-tom)

You should only blame Tomcat if you have clear evidence that Tomcat is responsible, and not your application.